# API call only delivers "1" instead of user data

Tags: php, facebook

If I use this piece of code:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => APP_ID,
  'secret' => APP_SECRET,
  'cookie' => true,
));

?>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>

  <?
   $user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $userData = $facebook->api("/me");
    echo "Name: " . $userData['name'];
    echo "<br>userData: " . print_r($userData);
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// If a user haven't been loged in, so the user have to authorize
if (!$user) {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
            array(
                'scope' => 'publish_stream',
                'redirect_uri' => APP_BASEHREF
            )
    );
    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $loginUrl . "'</script>");

}
```

I only get this response:

> Name: userData: 1

I don't know the issue. The user is correctly logged in.
I also try it with some test users with the same problem. It seems that the API call does not work correctly, but why?
Please can you help me?

Still no solution, can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `print_r($userData, true)`.

Comment: @MichaelK.Großklos no, you did `print_r($userData);` you need the extra parameter to "return as string"

Comment: i changed this because of your post. but nothing changed. it is not a problem of the print_r. as you can see the echo for $userData['name'] one line above also doesn't work.